# Get JSON object from string in python

Tags: python, json

Minimal working example:

```
import json, urllib

front_url = "http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/search/titles/results/?city=&rows="
number_rows = "1"
middle_url = "&terms=&language=&lccn=&material_type=&year1=1690&year2=2016&labor=&county=&state=&frequency=&ethnicity=&page="
page = "1"
end_url = "&sort=relevance&format=json"

url = front_url + number_rows + middle_url + page + end_url

response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
```

The issues is that the `data` object recognizes the top level of JSON (`totalItems`, `endIndex`, `startIndex`, `itemsPerPage`, and `items`), however, the `items` object should also have sublevels that should be recognized (`essay`, `county`, `title_normal`, `lccn`, etc.). The code just spits out a messy string for the `items` object though if you do `data['items']`.

I want to be able to extract each of the different prices of information contained in the `items` layer ultimately to an array or something similar. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine.

You just didn't understood that `data['items']` is a `list`.

so, to access to each element of this list, you have to use indices from `0` to `len(data['items'])`.

**advice**: use `pprint` to see clear in your json file.

```
import json, urllib
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=1, width=80)

front_url = "http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/search/titles/results/?city=&rows="
number_rows = "1"
middle_url = "&terms=&language=&lccn=&material_type=&year1=1690&year2=2016&labor=&county=&state=&frequency=&ethnicity=&page="
page = "1"
end_url = "&sort=relevance&format=json"

url = front_url + number_rows + middle_url + page + end_url

response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())

pp.pprint(data['items'][0]) # [0] to get the first item
print  data['items'][0]['essay'] # get the essay element of the first item
print  data['items'][0]['country'] # get the country element of the first item
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example JSON data (in which you should have linked directly) you can clearly see that the `items` is a list of objects. In this case it is just one object with a key `essay`. And the value for this key is a list of strings (and in this case just one string).

This string though, is not JSON. It is XHTML. It is of course not parsed by `json.loads`.

I believe this string is what you call the 'messy string'. The other data in `items` is parsed just fine by `json.loads`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
for item in data['items']:
    print item['county']
    print item['title_normal']
    print item['lccn']
```

Which outputs the following because there is only a single item.

```
[u'Bates']
butler weekly times and the bates county record.
sn86063289
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly fine. You could iterate over all items.

```
import json
import urllib

URL_PATTERN = "http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/search/titles/results/" \
    "?rows={rows}" \
    "&year1={year1}" \
    "&year2={year2}" \
    "&page={page}" \
    "&sort={sort}" \
    "&format={format}"

rows = "1"
page = "1"
year1 = "1690"
year2 = "2016"
sort_kind = "relevance" 
response_kind = "json"

url = URL_PATTERN.format(rows=rows, page=page, year1=year1, year2=year2,
                         sort=sort_kind, format=response_kind)

response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())

for item in data.get("items", []):
    # Pretty print.
    print(json.dumps(item, indent=4))
```

Also, remember, if you are not using some filter option, you can simplify an URL like presented above.

`The Zen of Python` says:

> Beautiful is better than ugly.

and:

> Readability counts.

Comment: At the end - I really like the non-consistency (mixing snake_case and camerCase notations) of the API from related URL. :-)

Comment: hey @Tomasz , any idea why `year1`, `year2` filters might not work as expected ? I described here https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/20359/chronicling-america-query-data-with-year-range